# Calculate cumulative waiting time for assignments arriving to CELL

Tags: sql

I have a table that holds information about the next task that will be assigned to workers, and the date at which this assignment was scheduled from the program running in the background. The tasks are like assembling stuff, and come over automatic machines roaming around the factory. These factories stop first at a centralized compute, get the info, run through a first area to pick up components and then arrive at the employee stations.

| ID | POSIZIONE | SFC | PRIORITY | SHOP_ORDER | CELL_ID | PRODOTTO | QUANTITY | OLIO | VERNICE | STOCK | DATA_CONSEGNA | DATA_SCHEDULATA | DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15789121 | 44 | 838029990100.00.0001 | 700 | 54030408 | CELL32_01 | WA30 DRN71M4 | 1 | NULL | RAL7031 (grigio Blu) | NO-STOCK | 2024-02-23 | 2024-02-22 | 2024-02-19 09:14:11.417 |
| 15789159 | 82 | 836340920400.00.0001 | 700 | 53885314 | CELL21_01 | SA37/T DRN63M4 | 1 | NULL | RAL7031 (grigio Blu) | STOCK | 2024-03-06 | 2024-02-21 | 2024-02-19 09:14:11.417 |

Now, what I would like to do, is tell each worker on their assigned cell when will the next task come through. After that, I would also like to tell them how long it will be until the next one.

These tasks take an average of 2-3 minutes to reaching the cell from when they are first read from the automation at the centralized computer, and this is almost immediate so there's no delay for this.

The idea is that, if I am for example at CELL32_01, I would have a waiting time as follows:

- 2/3 minutes for roaming -> arrived

For the second cell, maybe CELL21_01 it would still be:

- 2/3 minutes for roaming -> arrived, because the two cells are different

But let's say, for example, the third line is again at CELL21_01. Then the time should be:

- 2/3 minutes for roaming for the FIRST task there
- PLUS 2/3 minutes for the second task here

I hope this is clear enough, I am not sure how to act on this. I am not super proficient with SQL, and working with window functions is the only thing I have in mind.

What I need to do is create a new table that will, in a basic form, hold information about the cell, and the waiting time for the next task as calculated from the information above, can I get some help with this? I tried to work on something:

```
WITH TaskInfo AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATA]) AS TaskNumber,
        LAG([CELL_ID]) OVER (ORDER BY [DATA]) AS PrevCell
    FROM 
        [MyTable]
),
CellWaitingTime AS (
    SELECT 
        [CELL_ID],
        [DATA],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [CELL_ID] = PrevCell THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [DATA]) AS TaskGroup,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG([DATA], 1, [DATA]) OVER (PARTITION BY [CELL_ID] ORDER BY [DATA]), [DATA]) AS TimeDiff
    FROM 
        TaskInfo
)
SELECT 
    [CELL_ID],
    [DATA],
    SUM(TimeDiff) OVER (PARTITION BY [CELL_ID], TaskGroup ORDER BY [DATA]) AS WaitingTime,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [DATA], LEAD([DATA]) OVER (PARTITION BY [CELL_ID], TaskGroup ORDER BY [DATA])) AS TimeUntilNextTask
INTO 
    [NewTableName]
FROM 
    CellWaitingTime
```

When I run this query on SSMS, it doesn't throw any error message, but no table gets created either.

Comment: SSMS is an IDE(like) application for products like SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, And Synapse. Why have you hatched both it and MySWL? They have *no* relation.

Comment: You also don't actually *ask* anything here. What is the question you're asking?

Comment: @ThomA sorry, it's because I am working on these tables using SSMS, I figured there might be a connection. I edited my question, hopefully it's clearer this way.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: We also need to know what database engine you are using; SQL is using by many products and your initial tags (that conflicted) I removed.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.